# Sending a message specifying a channel / Python Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def xsend(ctx, *, message):
    await Bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    await Bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='408104999038746635'), message)
```

I have this command that sends a message to a specific channel according to its id, but I would like to be able to choose which channel I would like to send this message to, like:

```
xsend "#namechannel" "mymessage"
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a channel [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to automatically convert the channel argument to a `discord.Channel` object:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def xsend(ctx, channel: discord.Channel, *, message):
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    await bot.send_message(channel, message)
```